# Unable to install Canvas - NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm, canvas

I get an error when I run `npm install canvas` and try to use it like: `const canvas = require('canvas')`

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\josep\OneDrive\Desktop\Bots\Foundation\node_modules\canvas
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --update-binary
npm ERR! Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --update-binary --module=C:\Users\josep\OneDrive\Desktop\Bots\Foundation\node_modules\canvas\build\Release\canvas.node --module_name=canvas --module_path=C:\Users\josep\OneDrive\Desktop\Bots\Foundation\node_modules\canvas\build\Release --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v93 --python=C:\Users\josep\.windows-build-tools\python27\python.exe --msvs_version=2015' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@1.0.9
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node@16.15.0 | win32 | ia32
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http GET https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/releases/download/v2.9.3/canvas-v2.9.3-node-v93-win32-unknown-ia32.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! install response status 404 Not Found on https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/releases/download/v2.9.3/canvas-v2.9.3-node-v93-win32-unknown-ia32.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for canvas@2.9.3 and node@16.15.0 (node-v93 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error response status 404 Not Found on https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/releases/download/v2.9.3/canvas-v2.9.3-node-v93-win32-unknown-ia32.tar.gz
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.0.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.15.0 | win32 | ia32
npm ERR! gyp info ok
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.0.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.15.0 | win32 | ia32
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.10.5 found at "C:\Users\josep\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version was set from command line or npm config
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - looking for Visual Studio version 2015
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS checking VS2022 (17.2.32616.157) found at:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - found "Visual Studio C++ core features"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - found VC++ toolset: v143
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - found Windows SDK: 10.0.19041.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - msvs_version does not match this version
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS could not find a version of Visual Studio 2017 or newer to use
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - not found
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS valid versions for msvs_version:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - "2022"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.fail (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:122:47)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:75:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio2013 (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:363:14)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:71:14
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:384:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:54:7
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:33:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:406:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1092:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.22000
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--update-binary" "--module=C:\\Users\\josep\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Bots\\Foundation\\node_modules\\canvas\\build\\Release\\canvas.node" "--module_name=canvas" "--module_path=C:\\Users\\josep\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Bots\\Foundation\\node_modules\\canvas\\build\\Release" "--napi_version=8" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v93" "--python=C:\\Users\\josep\\.windows-build-tools\\python27\\python.exe" "--msvs_version=2015" 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\josep\OneDrive\Desktop\Bots\Foundation\node_modules\canvas
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.15.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.0.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --update-binary --module=C:\Users\josep\OneDrive\Desktop\Bots\Foundation\node_modules\canvas\build\Release\canvas.node --module_name=canvas --module_path=C:\Users\josep\OneDrive\Desktop\Bots\Foundation\node_modules\canvas\build\Release --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v93 --python=C:\Users\josep\.windows-build-tools\python27\python.exe --msvs_version=2015' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\josep\OneDrive\Desktop\Bots\Foundation\node_modules\@mapbox\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:89:23)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1092:16)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.22000
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\josep\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Bots\\Foundation\\node_modules\\@mapbox\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build" "--update-binary"
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\josep\OneDrive\Desktop\Bots\Foundation\node_modules\canvas
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v16.15.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v1.0.9
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
 
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\josep\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-07-12T17_23_56_341Z-debug-0.log
PS C:\Users\josep\OneDrive\Desktop\Bots\Foundation>
```

I have already installed `GTK` and stuff however I receive this error when I try installing `Canvas`.

Comment: Sorry, just noticed it was not a picture. The error message should be in your question. We should not have to follow links to understand your question.

Comment: It is too long to post

Comment: It is not! Errors should be here, I added it here for you..

Comment: The error says the following: `You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
For more information consult the documentation at:
https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows`

Comment: `404 Not Found` Check the releases: https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/releases does not look like there is any `...ia32.tar.gz` seems like only `x64` is supported

Comment: So I have to install VSCode..?

Comment: same error just missing build for nodejs 18 and cant find any alternative module for other module that require other module with v18. try now download Visual Studio 2015 build tools is like 120Mb but then another error message need desktop evn but this is only canvas library for nodejs or: https://www.npmjs.com/package/native-canvas

Answer (score 0):

At the begging, my node version is 16.10.0, after I use nvm change version to 14.10.0,the problem is resolved.
if not, you can checkout https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/issues/1733